# Error installing compass in OSX Yosemite (or Sierra)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, compass

Good day
I have a Mac with OSX Yosemite
I'm trying to install the compass with the command:

```
sudo gem install compass
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151001-1122-1jqcu8r.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-14/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out
```

before attempting to install the package I updated the gem with the command

```
sudo gem update --system
```

and the update occurred without errors

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: I do not see any problem in performing any questions from other areas that are related to programming

Comment: Please read help "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming."

Comment: The appropriate way to indicate that a problem is solved is by giving a checkmark to the correct answer, not by editing the question.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's the first time I use this channel and still do not know the best use of , the next time I will do the right way , thanks Marek H

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably need to install the command line developer tools first.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then try `sudo gem install compass` again

Comment: Thank Bert I solved my problem with your Thank bert I solved my problem with your answer

Comment: Great, glad to be of service. Could you also flag the answer as 'accepted'? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry but it's the first time I use this channel and still do not know the best use of.
I believe now marked correctly ?

Comment: This problem and solution also applies to macOS Sierra. Thank you.

Comment: And High Sierra too. And even if you have Xcode installed and working, it appears you still need to `xcode-select --install`.